# When is $\sigma(q^{k-1})$ a square when $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, integers, divisor-sum

Let $\sigma(x)$ be the sum of divisors of the positive integer $x$.

Here is my question:

> When is $\sigma(q^{k-1})$ a square when $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

$$r^2 = \frac{q^k - 1}{q - 1} = 1 + \ldots + q^{k-1} \equiv 1 + (k-1) \pmod 4 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$$
so that $r$ is odd.  Additionally, $r \equiv 1 \pmod q$.

Alas, that is where I get stuck.

**REVISED ATTEMPT**

Let $q$ be a prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

I prove here that

> $$\sigma(q^{k-1}) = s(q^k) \text{ is a square } \implies k = 1.$$

**Proof**

Assume to the contrary that $k > 1$.  This implies that $k \geq 5$ (since $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$).

Suppose that
$$s(q^k) = s^2 = \sigma(q^k) - q^k = \sigma(q^{k-1}) = \frac{q^k - 1}{q - 1}.\tag{$*$}$$

$(*)$ implies that $(q-1)s^2 = q^k - 1$, which is equivalent to
$$q(q^{k-1} - s^2) = q^k - qs^2 = 1 - s^2 = (1 + s)(1 - s) = -(s+1)(s-1).$$

Since $q$ is prime, we consider three cases:

*Case 1*: $q = s + 1$
$$\implies q - 1 = s \implies q^3 - 3q^2 + 3q - 1 = (q - 1)^3 = s^3 = (q - 1)s^2 = q^k - 1$$
$$\implies q^2 - 3q + 3 = q^{k-1} \geq q^4$$
This last inequality is a contradiction.

*Case 2*: $q = s - 1$
$$\implies q + 1 = s \implies q^{k-1} = s^2 - s - 1 = (q+1)^2 - (q+1) - 1$$ 
$$= q^2 + 2q + 1 - q - 1 - 1 = q^2 + q - 1$$
$$\implies q^2 + q - 1 = q^{k-1} \geq q^4$$
Again, this last inequality is a contradiction.

*Case 3*: $q = (s+1)(s-1)$
$$\implies q^{k-1} - s^2 = -1 \implies q^{k-1} = s^2 - 1 = q \implies k - 1 = 1 \implies k = 2.$$
However, we know that $k=2$ contradicts $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

**QED**

In fact, more is true.

> If $k=1$, then $s(q^k) \text{ is a square}$.
>
> > Therefore, we have the biconditional
> >     $$s(q^k) = \sigma(q^{k-1}) = \frac{q^k - 1}{q - 1}$$ is a square if and only if $k=1$.

Comment: What sort of answer are you expecting?  According to the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A006532), it isn't even known that there are infinitely many natural numbers $n$ with $\sigma (n)$ a perfect square (though of course that would follow quickly from standard conjectures).

Comment: @lulu, thank you for your comment.  I think an answer imposing further restrictions on the congruence classes for $q$ and $k$ would be acceptable for my purposes.

Comment: Well, from that OEIS link, you can get a list of the first $10,000$ examples of $n$ such that $\sigma (n)$ is a perfect square.  At least you can search that list for examples of the form you like.  That won't prove anything of course, but it ought to suffice to establish what the answer ought to look like.

Comment: @lulu, looking more closely at that OEIS link, it appears that Beukers, Luca and Oort has already proven that there are infinitely many $n$ for which $\sigma(n)$ is a square.  I will ask for a copy of their paper.  Thanks for pointing me to that OEIS reference.  =)

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that. Hope it helps.

Comment: The point of lulu is that it is obvious there is no simple way to ensure $\frac{q^k-1}{q-1}$ is a square, so you need to refine

Comment: @reuns, no worries.  I get lulu's point.

Comment: Posting a follow-up question in a bit.

Comment: Here is the follow-up [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3284709).